# Does changing regional timezone settings alter the "Modified" and "Created" fields on every list to fit that new timezone?

Tags: list, custom-field-types, timezone, modified

I realized that I was entering data into Sharepoint when the timezone settings was PST rather than EST. I changed it, but now it's taking a while for the automatic datetime fields ("Modified" and "Created") to reflect that change in the lists. I really do not want to have to reenter all my data so that they reflect the new standard.

I'm not just asking about new entries, but also entries that have already been made.

[image]

Above is a picture of the settings I used to change the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**
If you are asking only about Created and Modified fields - don't worry about these. You won't need to re-enter anything.

**More information**
SharePoint does not store date and time in PST or EST. Regardless of where you are in the world or what TimeZone you used, all dates are saved as UTC. UTC is always the same no matter where you are on the Planet.

When retreiving date and time values, SharePoint automatically converts UTC to your local time on-the-fly.

If you are using **custom fields** - it might have some different logic.

Comment: How long does it usually take for the Created and Modified fields to reflect the new timezone?

Comment: There are several ways to change the Timezone: User profile service, site level, Exchange, hidden user list, etc. So we need more details: 1) How exactly did you change the time zone? 2) Are you using SharePoint Online or On-premises? 3) Are you using Modern or classic SharePoint views?